aus der/durch die/zur Tür hinaus?
Ich habe im Internet drei verschiedene Übersetzungen für out of the door gefunden:

aus der Tür hinaus
durch die Tür hinaus
zur Tür hinaus

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen denen? Sagen sie inhaltlich dasselbe? Welches ist zu bevorzugen?
Eine Tür/ein Tor ist ja eigentlich weder innen noch außen, es liegt auf der Grenze, aber man muss es durchqueren, um rein oder raus zu kommen. Darum wäre "durch" für mich das logischste. Hingegen legen die Formulierungen 1 und 3 wahrscheinlich mehr Fokus auf die Bewegung, wobei die Bewegung ja auch durch das angehängte "hinaus" kenntlich wird.

Von der Bedeutung her gibt es zwischen "zur Tür hinaus" und "aus der Tür hinaus" kaum Unterschiede.
Eine Korpussuche nach "Tür {hinaus,heraus,raus}" zeigt klar, dass "zur Tür hinaus" die häufigste und normalste Art ist, das zu sagen. Vor "heraus" ist allerdings "aus der Tür heraus" häufiger. Ich vermute, das liegt an der Perspektive: Wenn man durch eine Tür geht, geht man erst zu der Tür, dann aus der Tür. Verlässt jemand den Sprecher, so ist klar, dass er die Bewegung zur Tür sieht. Kommt jemand zum Sprecher, so sieht er eher die Bewegung aus der Tür.
"Durch die Tür hinaus" legt den Fokus aber auf die Tür. In fast allen Beispielen für "durch #<5 Tür hinaus" wird die Tür noch irgendwie (z.B. geschlossen, schmale) beschrieben. Hierbei wird der Fokus darauf gelegt, welche Tür es ist. Dagegen wird bei "zur Tür hinaus" selten die Tür irgendwie beschrieben().
Außerdem gibt es noch "die Tür hinaus" mit ebenfalls ähnlicher Bedeutung.
Zu "aus der Tür raus" noch: Wenn jemand in der Tür steht (und damit im Weg steht), kann man ihn bitten aus der Tür raus zu gehen, aber eher nicht "durch" oder "zur Tür" raus zu gehen.
